# design of Python API - initializing high level classes

Tags: python

I am working on a Python API that communicates with an HTTP API, but could use some guidance on the overall design of my API.  (The python API's user base is very small; primarily myself, and sometimes a few others)  I'm writing it in Python 3, but trying to keep it 2.7 compatible.

I have a Client class that represents a client connection and which has a number of methods that all correspond one-to-one to an HTTP call.  Creation of a Client instance requires the user's credentials, which are passed to __init__.

I am now putting together a couple other classes that further abstract the methods from the Client class.  In order for classes and their methods to work, they need an instance of Client.

I can think of a couple ways to get this

1. Have the classes' __init__s accept an instance of Client.
2. Have the classes' __init__s accept the user's credentials and setup a Client instance
3. Subclass the Client class

Any thoughts on what the best way to this?  (It does not need to be one of the things I've thought of.)

I would also be interested if there are any good examples of design, I could look to for inspiration.

Comment: I think this question is probably off-topic here, because the answer is a matter of opinion.  I will note that many of the OpenStack Python libraries allow both (1) and (2) -- you can pass in an existing authentication client, or you can pass in credentials and the class will instantiate an authentication client internally.  Certainly accepting an existing client object can both simplify your code and reduce the number of times a client must authenticate, which can have both performance and auditing benefits.

Comment: About being off-topic - I agree, this is a question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ And about question itself: what are those other classes? I can imagine both a shopping cart that has to be connected to the client as well as "paying client" which has more functionalities available, but besides them he needs user credentials. In both those situation API would look totally different. Anyway, (2) doesn't seem nice to me - explicit is better than implicit and you would create a Client instance implicitly.

Comment: @FilipMalczak this question is perhaps too broad for Programmers.SE, and the resource request in the final paragraph is off-topic at both sites. While design review is on-topic at Programmers, we expect askers to present a bit more work and not just ask "how do I design this?" Before recommending other users to ask on Programmers, please read **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/22815)**.

Comment: Thanks for comments.  I did consider that this might be a matter of opinion, but was hoping that there was a way that was generally considered more Pythonic than the other.  In any case, apologies for asking a question that is off topic for stackoverflow.